What is the significance of 1 SD?
This might be a noob question but "why" is 1 standard deviation what it is? AFAIK, the derivative at 1 SD is ±1 (is it?) but why does that matter? Couldn't you define 1 SD as the point where the derivate was e or π or some other "interesting" constant? Furthermore, 1 SD covers about 68 % - again, is there something special with 68 %, why not 2/3 or 50 % or 80 % (because of the 80-20 rule of thumb)?

What do you mean by "the derivative at 1 SD is +- 1"? Derivative of what? If you mean of a density plot, then what distribution? The normal? Different distributions will have different derivatives at 1 SD from the mean.

Even specifying the normal would be insufficient. That derivative depends on $\sigma$

The (or a or one) standard deviation

is the square root of the variance and
has the same units as the data and is a measure of the scale of the distribution

and this is why that statistic is considered.
It has some additional properties (e.g. part of the distribution is no more than one standard deviation from the expectation and part of the distribution is no less than one standard deviation from the expectation; $1$ standard deviation above or below the expectation are the inflection points of a normal density curve), but they are ancillary to this main point of the relationship to the variance and the scale.

I don't fully understand what you are saying about derivatives but I don't think  that is a helpful way of understanding what a standard deviation is. Part of the issue is I think you are confusing the concept of standard deviation in general with the standard deviation of a normal curve.
Here is the most basic way to think about it. Any statistical distribution, no matter what its shape (bell shaped, flat, two humped, whatever) has a mean - an average value. The standard deviation tells how "close" the other values are to that mean value, "on average". To calculate the standard deviation you basically find the distance from each point to the mean and then take the average of those distances (really you take the average of the squares of those distances and then take the square root of that average). So if you have a standard deviation of 2.5 that means (more or less) that the mean distance between each point and the mean is 2.5. So a standard deviation of 1 just means that the average value is within 1 point of the mean.
That's standard deviations in general. Now, the normal (gaussian) curve is a very special bell shaped distribution that (among other things) describes the way that random errors deviate from a true value (its formula does have the numbers "e" and "pi" in it, but that's not especially relevant in this context), and for that reason it can can tell us about how much error we should expect from an estimate drawn from a random sample. Because of this, we know quite a bit about this distribution and one thing we happen to know is that, if you standardize it so that the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is 1, we can figure out the % of observations that are between any two sets of values. So we know that ~68% of observations are between -1 and 1 standard deviations, or that ~95% are between -1.96 and 1.96 standard deviations (and 1.96 is pretty close to 2). There is nothing special about those numbers per se, but because we know them we can use them to compute common standards for deciding if a finding is "real" as opposed to just due to random error.
